# .c files in development of python language

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, github-pages

There is no .c file in the python distribution that I download from https://www.python.org/downloads. However, in the CPython GitHub repository of python (https://github.com/python/cpython), there are many .c files. From development phase to distribution where do these .c files go and what purpose they serve in the development of the Python language itself? I am using pyton3.6.4 on windows 8.1.

Comment: The .c files contain C source code. C source code can't be executed directly; it needs to be compiled first. Generally the compiled executable is distributed for convenience, often without the source code itself.

Answer (score 3):

They go to the same place most source files go when you create executables - into the executables. Once source code has been translated into executable code, only the *latter* is generally required to run the code. The source is only needed if you want to *change* the program in some way.

It's the same as all the source files that go toward Microsoft Windows, Libre Office, or the Oracle DBMS. To run them, you only need the executables.

Keep in mind that, though open source software may ship the source, this is not required to run the program. It's shipped for a philosophical reason rather than a functional one.